# Functions defined in dynamically-loaded scripts cannot refer to each other

Tags: python, ipython, read-eval-print-loop, execfile

I'm trying to load functions from a script dynamically when I'm inside an ipython interactive shell. For example, suppose I have a python script like this:

```
# script.py
import IPython as ip

def Reload():
  execfile('routines.py', {}, globals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ip.embed()
```

Suppose the file routines.py is like this:

```
# routines.py
def f():
  print 'help me please.'
def g():
  f()
```

Now if I run the script script.py, I'll be entering the interactive shell. If I type the following, my call to g() works:

```
execfile('routines.py')
g()
```

However, if I type the following, the call to g() fails:

```
Reload()
g()
```

I will get an error message saying that **"global name f is not defined."**, although I can still see that f and g are in the output when I type globals() in the interactive shell.

What's the difference of these two?

UPDATE:

The following works, however it's not a preferred solution so I would like to have a better solution for the problem above.

If I change script.py to:

```
# script.py
import IPython as ip

def Reload():
  execfile('routines.py')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ip.embed()
```

And change routines.py to:

```
# routines.py

global f
global g

def f():
  print 'help me please.'
def g():
  f()
```

Then if I call Reload() in the interactive shell and then call g(), it works. However this is not a preferred approach because I have to declare global names.

UPDATE 2:

It seems that the problem is independent of ipython. With the first version of routines.py if I start the python shell, and type the following by hand:

```
def Reload():
  execfile('routines.py', {}, globals())

g()
```

The call to g() also fails. But the following works:

```
execfile('routines.py')
g()
```

Comment: Why are you using `execfile`? Just import the module: `from routines import *`.

Comment: Sorry for some reason I'm not able to do that. I also made a mistake in describing the problem and now I updated it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bakuriu said, importing is much preferred. Ignoring that, what you want is

```
def Reload():
    execfile('routines.py', globals())
```

Lets clarify your example to show why it does not work.

```
# Setup the namespace to use for execfile
global_dict = {}
local_dict = globals()
execfile('routines.py', global_dict, local_dict)
g() # raises NameError
```

Since you are passing two different dicts to `execfile`, the file is executed as if it were in a class definition ([from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile)). This means your functions are defined in `local_dict` but not `global_dict`.

When you then call `g()`, it is executed using globals `global_dict` and a fresh empty local dict. Since neither `global_dict` or the new locals doesn't contain `f` we get a name error. By instead calling `execfile('routines.py', globals())`, we are using `global_dict = globals()` and `local_dict = globals()` so `f` is defined in `g`'s globals.

EDIT:

You noticed that `local_dict` has both `f` and `g`, but `global_dict` does not in the second example. Defining any variable without explicitly marking it global will always make a local variable, this applies to modules too! It just so happens that normally a module has `locals() == globals()`; however, we broke this standard by using different local and global dicts. This is what I meant when I said "the file is executed as if it were in a class definition".

Comment: In fact, if I ran the second code segment you put, I can see f and g in local_dict but not in global_dict. Can you explain why?

Comment: @shaoyl85 see my edit, hopefully that clears it up. If you have anymore questions feel free to ask.